# How to display System.Collection on ListView Xamarin

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

**I have a system collection and want to display on `ListView` two columns *dateForecast*  and *levelForecast* from `IEnumerable<AlertLevel>`.**

[image: arg my system collection]

This is my `ListView` and `GoogleFormMap`:

```
 <Grid>
  
  <Label Text="Hydro Forecast Maritsa-Tundzha"
         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
         FontSize="Large"
         FontAttributes="Bold"
         Margin="0,40,0,0"/>
   <StackLayout>
       <ListView x:Name="lstLevel">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                       Text="{Binding DateLevel}"
                                       Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
                                 <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                       Text="{Binding AlertLevel}"
                                       Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
   </StackLayout>
    <Grid Margin="0,70,0,10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="250" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout>
          <local:CustomMap x:Name="customMap"
                           MapType="Street"
                           HasZoomEnabled="True"
                           HasScrollEnabled="False"/>
      </StackLayout>
    </Grid>     
</Grid>
```

**And I want to display the data in this method:**

```
 public void MarkerPressed()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, IEnumerable<AlertLevel>>(this, "PinSelected", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            ListView lstLevel = (sender as ListView);
            lstLevel.BindingContext = arg;
        });
    }
```

When I click on marker in the map I receive this error message:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException has been thrown: 

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

And the error send me on this method in android project in class `CustomMapRenderer.cs`:

```
CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
    {
        string id = annotation.Id.Substring(1);

        int mapCode = int.Parse(id);

        var result = DataBaseConnection(mapCode);

        MessagingCenter.Send<object, IEnumerable<AlertLevel>>(this, "PinSelected", result);

        var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);

        foreach (var pin in customPins)
        {
            if (pin.Position == position)
            {
                return pin;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is all code in the `CustomMapRenderer.cs` in my android project:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Widget;
using MaritsaTundzhaForecast;
using MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Models;
using MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Droid;
using MySqlConnector;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Droid
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
    {
        List<CustomPin> customPins;

        public CustomMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
        {
            base.OnMapReady(map);

            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
            NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
        }

        protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
        {
            var marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
            marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
            marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
            //marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.green));

            var custom = customPins.Where(x => x.Label == pin.Label && x.Address == pin.Address).FirstOrDefault();

            if (custom != null)
            {
                if (custom.AlertLevel == 1)
                {
                    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.green));
                }
                if (custom.AlertLevel == 2)
                {
                    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.yellow));
                }
                if (custom.AlertLevel == 3)
                {
                    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.orange));
                }
                if (custom.AlertLevel == 4)
                {
                    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.red));
                }
            }
            return marker;
        }

        void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPin.Url))
            {
                var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, url);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
        {
            var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
            if (inflater != null)
            {
                Android.Views.View view;

                var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
                if (customPin == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
                }

                if (customPin.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XamarinMapInfoWindow, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow, null);
                }

                CustomPin pin = GetCustomPin(marker);

                int CodeNum = pin.CodeNum;
                int AlertLevel = pin.AlertLevel;

                var infoTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowTitle);
                var infoSubtitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle);
                var infoSubtitle2 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle2);
                var infoSubtitle3 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle3);

                if (infoTitle != null)
                {
                    infoTitle.Text = marker.Title;
                }
                if (infoSubtitle != null)
                {
                    infoSubtitle.Text = marker.Snippet;
                }
                if (infoSubtitle2 != null)
                {
                    infoSubtitle2.Text = "Тревога: (1-4): " + AlertLevel;
                }
                if (infoSubtitle3 != null)
                {
                    infoSubtitle3.Text = "Код на станция: " + CodeNum;
                }

                return view;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<AlertLevel> DataBaseConnection(int mapCode)
        {
            string ConnectionString = "server=192.168.0.1;uid=userName;port=3387;pwd=password;database=dbName;";
            MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            var listAlert = new List<AlertLevel>();

            try
            {
                Conn.Open();

                //replace(2) with mapCode
                string query = "CALL Get_Alert_levels_Station(" + mapCode + ");";
                MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, Conn);
                MySqlDataReader myReader;

                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                try
                {
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        var currentData = new AlertLevel()
                        {
                            
                            dateForecast = myReader.GetDateTime(0),
                            levelForecast = myReader.GetInt32(1)
                            
                        };

                        listAlert.Add(currentData);
                    } 
                }
                finally
                {
                    myReader.Close();
                    Conn.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Database Connection", "Not Connected ..." + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString(), "OK");
            }

            return listAlert;
        }

        CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
        {
            string id = annotation.Id.Substring(1);

            int mapCode = int.Parse(id);

            var result = DataBaseConnection(mapCode);

            MessagingCenter.Send<object, IEnumerable<AlertLevel>>(this, "PinSelected", result);

            var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);

            foreach (var pin in customPins)
            {
                if (pin.Position == position)
                {
                    return pin;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Can I get some example how to fix this error ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `BindingContext` property of the `ListView`.

if the sender in your case is your `ListView` then :

```
        ListView yourListView = (sender as ListView);
        yourListView.BindingContext = yourCollection;
```

if not then give your `ListView` a name ( use `x:Name` property in xaml) then access the `BindingContext` property in your code behind.

if you method is located in your `ViewModel` just bind your `ListView` to it :

```
<ListView x:Name="lstLevel" ItemsSource="{Binding yourCollectionName}" ItemTapped="RowItemTapped">
```

Comment: I have a trouble with your way I will update the question. Can you check, please..

Comment: Put a breakpoint into this line "ListView lstLevel = (sender as ListView); and make sure that the cast in working and giving you your ListView , go to the next line and make sure that after setting the BindingContext your ItemsSource contains the expected collection (if not try to set directly the ItemsSource property instead of BindingContext ), if the ItemsSource has the expected values then you have a problem with the map control Custom Renderer.

Comment: try also to use an observable collection : new ObservableCollection<AlertLevel>(arg)

Answer (score 1):

just assign the `ItemSource` of your `ListView`

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, IEnumerable<AlertLevel>>(this, "PinSelected", async (sender, arg) =>
    {
       lstLevel.ItemsSource = arg;
    });
```

Comment: Jason with your method When I click on the marker the listview is showing, but is empty.. I not have any errors but I can't see the data on the listview ;(

Comment: I just use lstLevel.ItemsSource = arg; and this work without any errors but, why my listview is empty ?

Comment: have you verified that `arg` contain your data?

Comment: Yes I upload a screenshot on arg in the question.

Comment: `Text="{Binding DateLevel}"` but there is no property `DateLevel` in the screenshot

Comment: What can I do to see the data ?

Comment: fix your binding expression to match the actual property names in your model

Comment: lstLevel.ItemsSource = arg; here I cannot call DataLevel.ItemSource, I not understand what can I do ?

Comment: fix `Text="{Binding DateLevel}"` - based on your screenshot there is not a property named "DateLevel" on your model.  Change it to match the actual property name in your model.